# Image clickable in Recycle View in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I make a simple custom list with the help of RecyclerView in android and i have done it, Different pic is use in custom list,  I want to make image click able individually. Suggest me some tips.

Below is the pic of my custom list:

[image]

I want to make the like and dislike image clickable.

below is may recycleView Adpter:

```
    public class recycleReviewAdpter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recycleReviewAdpter.myViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    List<single_row_data> data;

    public recycleReviewAdpter(Context context ,List<single_row_data> data) {
        this.context=context;
        this.data=data;
    }

    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singel_row, null);
        myViewHolder myViewHolder=new myViewHolder(view);

        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.titelText.setText(data.get(position).getTitel());
        holder.shareImage.setImageResource(data.get(position).getSharePic());
        holder.likeImage.setImageResource(data.get(position).getLikePic());
        holder.disLikeImage.setImageResource(data.get(position).getDisLikePic());
        holder.image.setImageResource(data.get(position).getImage());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
      class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public ImageView likeImage,disLikeImage,shareImage,image;
        public TextView  titelText;

        public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            likeImage= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeImage);
            disLikeImage= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dislikeImage);
            shareImage= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareImage);
            image= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            titelText= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titelText);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int id=v.getId();

            switch (id){
                case R.id.likeImage:
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Like",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.dislikeImage:
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Like",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.shareImage:
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"share",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                default:Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Nohting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Did you try clickListener? If you did, post the code and we can debug why it did not work

Comment: i want to make only three image (Like,Dislike,Share) clickable, i post my code as well.Tell me please what i do.

Answer (score 1):

your code is pretty good.
just do that simple thing
for every imageview

```
public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        likeImage= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeImage);
        likeImage.setonclickListner(this);
    }
```

Comment: i also have same problem.works your solution @VishalPatel

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {


    viewHolder.MovieName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
            Toast.makeText(c,"Movie Name clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do your stuff

        }
    });
}
```